# Textcomp Package Overriding Gensymb for Degree Symbol

Tags: pdftex, symbols, textcomp, degrees

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\noindent 45$\degree$ \\
45$^\circ$\\
%45\textdegree
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Upon inspection, it would appear that `45$\degree$` and `45$^\circ$` produce exactly the same glyph.

Now, if I uncomment `%\usepackage{textcomp}` and `%45\textdegree` within the above code and run it, I get

[image]

Notice that `45$\degree$` seemingly now renders `45\textdegree`; while `45$^\circ$` seems to produce the same glyph as before.

QUESTION: Are there other symbols for which `textcomp` "trumps" `gensymb`? Can anyone explain what might be causing this; and perhaps, how I may override it so that if I call for both the `gensymb` and `textcomp` packages in the preamble and invoke, say, the `\degree` command in the document---I get what `\degree` normally produces?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I compile

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

$45\degree$

$45^\circ$

45\textdegree

\end{document}
```

with TeX Live 2012, prior to the inclusion of `textcomp` in the kernel, I get

[image]

and an error about `\textdegree` if I comment out `\usepackage{textcomp}`. The output from the first two lines becomes

[image]

So the aim of `gensymb` has *always* been using the smaller glyph from `textcomp` if possible.

It achieves this by doing

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}
    {\gns@setupmathcomp\gns@usetcsymbols}%
    {\gns@usefakedsymbols}
  [...]
}
```

Unfortunately the package has not been updated for keeping up with the inclusion of `textcomp` in the kernel, so it doesn't actually realize that `\textdegree` is available even if `textcomp` is not loaded. If you load it, the output is as expected by the author of `gensymb`.

I'm not sure why you think that `textcomp` “trumps” `gensymb`: the behavior is *wanted*.

To be honest, I'd avoid loading `gensymb` that provides nothing that isn't available in different ways. Anyway, you can get a shortened `gensymb` by

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{gns@font}{TS1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\ifx\mv@bold\@undefined\else
  \SetSymbolFont{gns@font}{bold}{TS1}{\familydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\fi
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tccelsius}{\mathord}{gns@font}{137}     % {'211}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tcdegree}{\mathord}{gns@font}{176}      % {'260}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tcperthousand}{\mathord}{gns@font}{135} % {'207}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tcmu}{\mathord}{gns@font}{181}          % {'265}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tcohm}{\mathord}{gns@font}{87}          % {'127}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\degree}{%
  \ifmmode\tcdegree\else\textdegree\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\celsius}{%
  \ifmmode\tccelsius\else\textcelsius\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\perthousand}{%
  \ifmmode\tcperthousand\else\textperthousand\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ohm}{\ifmmode\tcohm\else\textohm\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\micro}{\ifmmode\tcmu\else\textmu\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$45\degree$

$45^\circ$

45\textdegree

\degree,\celsius,\perthousand,\ohm,\micro

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just need `\degree`, there's no point in wasting a math group:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\degree}{}
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF
   {
    \text
     {
      \normalfont
      \str_if_eq:vnT { math@version } { bold } { \bfseries }
      \textdegree
     }
   }
   {
    \textdegree
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$45\degree$

$45^\circ$

45\textdegree

\boldmath $45\degree$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.

Comment: +1: Where would be a canonical place to look for a list of available build-in symbols for core Latex now that, for example, textcomp is included in the core? Or would that be another question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The forthcoming new edition of the LaTeX Companion

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. `\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}` does not seem to be relevant.
2. According to https://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp, the **`textcomp` package is obsolete** and now "part of the [LATEX distribution](https://ctan.org/pkg/latex)".
3. The below adapted code shows the (for me) expected behavior.

### [image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\noindent 45$\degree$ \texttt{\textbackslash degree} (math mode)\\
45$^\circ$ \texttt{\textbackslash circ} (math mode)\\
45\textdegree\ \texttt{\textbackslash textdegree} (text mode)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: I compiled this using Overleaf with the following settings. When I use pdfLaTeX instead, then the result looks a bit different.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for the lualatex code (though the actual document document is compiled with pdflatex). I got it to work after uncommenting out `%\usepackage{textcomp}`. The ams packages I invoked was an oversight on my part---leftover, perhaps, from another set of code I modified for this question. As for your PDFLatex illustration, do you know if there is a way to produce the output without Overleaf?  Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @mlchristians I am too busy atm for a better answer (dealing with an Udacity course) but I suggest that you update your LaTeX installation. Overleaf is "just" using a normal TeXLive AFAIK.